# What is the name of this drink and is there a substitute for the pineapple?

Tags: substitutions, milk, drinks, pineapple

[image]

In many cities in the Venezuelan Andes, there is a traditional beverage with the following preparation:

Put a slice/piece of pineapple about two inches per side in a bottle of milk.

Put the milk with the pineaple in the refrigerator for about 4 hours.

Take the milk, without the pineapple, and shake a little with a spoon to homohenize, then put about 2 oz in a milkshake machine, and shake for about 1 minute puting suggar in the process.

Optionaly put some artifitial flavor in the milkshake machine - I'd recomend coconut artifitial flavor. Also you can put in the milkshake machine with the milk, some small pices of ice cubes, this makes the drink a bit more creamy.

This is usually a companion for [Empanadas or Pasteles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empanada)

**What is the name of this beverage? Is a powder or something else that substitutes the pineapple piece and/or the fermentation process?**

I googled for something like this with no luck, the closest recipe is the pineapple-coconut milk, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just curiosity ... What city is that?

Comment: I haven't heard of soaking pineapple in milk, but I have seen pineapple-coconut milk smoothie recipes that use just coconut milk + pineapple + sweeteners.

Comment: Is it similar to *chicha andina*?

Comment: @PeterTaylor the chicha andina is another traditional drink in the andes, that one together with the mazato, are made of corn, barley, rice or alikes, with sugar, passing through a fermetation process. the one I've descrived is another drink, that is only milk fermentated with the sugar in the pineapple

Comment: See also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/31897/are-smoothies-and-milk-shakes-the-same-things-with-different-names/31898#31898

Comment: +1 for the picture. That looks well worth trying at home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the description of how this beverage is made, it is not fermented.  Four hours, at refrigerator temperature, and without any inoculation from an active bacterial culture simply will not cause any significant amount of fermentation.

Instead, what is happening is that the enzyme bromelin and acid present in pineapple is curdling the milk proteins, lending it a thicker texture.  This is very analogous to some types of cheese making.

I was not able to determine a name for this beverage.

Comment: hmmm... I'm lactose intolerant, that would explain why this drink doesn't cause me digestive problems unlike milk alone.

Comment: Fresh cheeses usually still contain lactose, but possibly a smaller amount than the milk that they're made of. However, I don't think there is a difference after only four hours....

Comment: The enzyme acts on proteins, and because there is no true fermentation, I would suspect there is little or no reduction in the amount of lactose present in the milk.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I've found [this article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0Q6MtYWaIncJ:www.kit.nl/library/query.ashx%3FRecordID%3D583291+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=safari) but frankly I'm not sure if it's the the same drink. It appears that pineapple can ferment in three hours at 43 ºC. That would explain the lactose diminution.

Comment: 43 C is 110 F -- definitely not refrigerator temperature!  Also, the industrial process described begins by innoculating the milk with a specific culture of lactobacillus.  So it is essentially a liquid yohurt--probably very enjoyable to the same palette that likes the pineapple drink--but a different beverage.